# How to make scalable game mastermind with API

Tags: java, api, oop, solid-principles

I want to create an API for [mastermind game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). The main features of that API are:

- 1 - Create a new game
- 2 - Return feedback given a game code and the guess combination
- 3 - Return game historic given a game code

My main idea is to use an embedded database (like could be H2), and then the feature 1 would be just an insert of new games, and the other features would be just to check the database status. Obviously with that approach, any request would need a database request, and I think that could be improved using some kind of cache (maybe redis), and cache the status of every game using LRU strategy.

I would like to know if you see any inconvenience to this game implementation approach (or another better approach maybe just using memory data structures instead of databases).

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) means. The API describes/defines the methods that can be called. Any discussion of embedded database is immaterial to the API, because that is an *implementation* issue. The same API could be implemented by storing data in a plain file, or by only storing the data in memory. You seem to be talking about the implementation, not the API itself.

Comment: Sure, I want to create an API for that game, but my issues are with the implementation, that I would like to know if my approach is good. My fault, sorry!

Comment: Aren't you missing a very important part of the API, the ability to actually *play* the game?

Comment: The ability to play the game is via API. When a new game is requested, it "creates" a code and id (for instance, 123; RED, BLUE, RED, BLUE), code needs to be found using guesses (for instance, game 123; RED, BLUE, BLUE, RED) which the API would return how many pegs were correct.

Comment: But you only listed 3 features in the API, and none of them are for submitting a new guess.

Comment: You are right! Fixed.

Comment: That looks fantastic @Gerardo, please provide a link when you have completed the game so we can all have a look.